# What is the preferred way to declare a form in django?

Tags: django-forms

What is the preferred way to declare a form in django? And why 1 way verse the other way?

I've seen this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='My Name', help_text='My help text.')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name']
```

And I’ve seen this:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name']
        labels = {'name': 'My Name'}
        help_texts= {'name': 'My help text'}
```